# Htaccess rule to ignore files that don't exist?

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I have the following site structure:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php --> main entry for Zend
http://www.mysite.com/.htaccess --> the htaccess file
http://www.mysite.com/models/index.php --> a NON-zend subsite.
```

My problem is that because we allow several other sites to serve http://www.mysite.com/models/index.php, we are getting several errors in our log, e.g:

```
 [error] File does not exist: /mnt/models/files/assets/seo/file.gif
```

In other words, other sites are calling models/index.php but because of the way they are including it, other non-existing paths are also called. E.g.:

```
http://www.mysite.com/models/files/assets/seo/file.gif
```

I want to include a rule in the htaccess file that will stop all non existing files from being reported to ZEND.

In the ZEND htaccess file, I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

How can I include something in the htaccess file that will ignore non-existing files in models/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is probably to ignore any requests to `models/`. Add this line above your existing rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/models)
```